# What is the format of the -x parameter on ./gradle?

Tags: gradle, command-line

Let's say I have some gradle task named:

`:ProjectName:SubProjectName1:SubProjectName2:copyFiles`

that I want to ignore. and I want to run the build task without having that run.

To be clear, I don't want to ignore all `copyFiles`, just `:ProjectName:SubProjectName1:SubProjectName2:copyFiles`.

Do I just do `./gradle -x :ProjectName:SubProjectName1:SubProjectName2:copyFiles build` ?

Can it use wildcards? I.e. `./gradle -x :ProjectName:SubProjectName1:SubProjectName2:* build` ?

Where can I find documentation that describes what formats are acceptable for this -x parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Github code is the best help here

[class StartParameter](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/0a171602dc8c640a9c4daf586106cca32e3b504a/subprojects/core/src/main/java/org/gradle/StartParameter.java#L349)

```
    /**
     * Returns the names of the tasks to be excluded from this build. When empty, no tasks are excluded from the build.
     *
     * @return The names of the excluded tasks. Returns an empty set if there are no such tasks.
     */
    public Set<String> getExcludedTaskNames() {
        return excludedTaskNames;
    }
```

[class ExcludedTaskFilteringBuildConfigurationAction](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/f001402c8b7f404c923d972f1bc524b2de7b3fcd/subprojects/core/src/main/java/org/gradle/execution/ExcludedTaskFilteringBuildConfigurationAction.java)

```
public void configure(BuildExecutionContext context) {
    GradleInternal gradle = context.getGradle();
    Set<String> excludedTaskNames = gradle.getStartParameter().getExcludedTaskNames();
    if (!excludedTaskNames.isEmpty()) {
        final Set<Spec<Task>> filters = new HashSet<Spec<Task>>();
        for (String taskName : excludedTaskNames) {
            filters.add(taskSelector.getFilter(taskName));
        }
        gradle.getTaskGraph().useFilter(Specs.intersect(filters));
    }

    context.proceed();
}
```

As you can see, wildcards are not supported, `-x` refers to task names.

Comment: and yes you can specify just tasks "build" for example... or you can specify absolute tasks like ":MyProj:MySubProj:build"